# update a specific field inside a JSON typed field using mongoose on linux

Tags: json, linux, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a specific value inside of a json typed field.

My document schema looks something like this:

```
character
{
    name: {type: string},
    experience: {type: json}
    ...
}
```

I make sure experience always contains a json object with 2 fields:

```
{ unspent: number, total: number }
```

I'm trying to make a generic update method, and on windows that works fine:

```
'update': function (itemid, update, callback) {
    model.update({'id': itemid}, update, {multi: false}, callback);
}
```

the update gets a req.body.fields object, which is a json object containing the 'fields' i want updated, e.g.

```
{'experience.total': 5}
```

This works fine when i run it on my windows dev box. When I try it on my linux staging server however, mongoose doesn't seem to pick up what it needs to update.

I have no problem updating other fields (like 'name' in my example)

thanks!

Comment: `json` is not one of the standard Mongoose types, do you mean `Mixed`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the type i used is JSON...

 'Character': mongoose.model('character',{
        id: {unique: true, type: String},
        type: {type: String},
        name: {type: String},
        googleId: {type: String},
        player: {type: JSON},
        chronicle: {type: JSON},
        state: {type: String},
        experience: {type: JSON}
....}

Comment: I don't know where i got the 'JSON' type thingie from. Probably a bad example I started with.
I've changed the type to Schema.Types.Mixed, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: OK. If `experience` always contains `unspent` and `total` fields like you describe, why aren't you defining it that way in your schema instead of using `Mixed`?

Comment: Learning as we go. I've changed it to 
        experience: {
            unspent: String,
            total: String
            },

And I've cleaned / refreshed all my data. However, the problem still remains the same: mongoose silently fails to update.

Comment: Also, since you mentioned the Mixed thing, I found a lot of useful related links. So I have tried marking my fields as modified and using the save functionality of the document instead of update. It still fails without throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around and with the help of JohnnyHK if found a solution:

don't use a JSON type (i wish mongoose would complain my schema was invalid)
don't use Mixed type when you know what your type looks like.

After I changed my schema to this:

```
experience: {
    unspent: String,
    total: String
    },
```

and reverted my .markModified and .Save() functionality back to it's origal form using update, it worked!